# Referencing EPPlus .Net library in IronPython

Tags: .net, ironpython, epplus

I'm trying to use the EPPlus Dot Net library from IronPython to open and update an Excel spreadsheet, but I cannot establish a reference to the library.  I'm not sure whether the problem is in my code, my understanding of referencing Dot net libraries (which is very basic), the way in which I downloaded and "installed" the dll, or whether it simply is not compatible with IronPython.

Can anybody suggest how I can reference this library from IronPython?

Here's my python code:

```
import sys
from collections import OrderedDict
sys.path.append(r'C:\EPPlus')
import clr
clr.AddReference('WindowsBase')
clr.AddReferenceToFile('EPPlus.dll')  # Fails here.
```

The code fails on `clr.AddReferenceToFile('EPPlus.dll')` with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "auction_support_epp.py", line 6, in <module>
IOError: System.IO.IOException: Could not add reference to assembly EPPlus.dll
   at IronPython.Runtime.ClrModule.AddReferenceToFile(CodeContext context, Strin
g file)
. . .
```

Here's a directory listing of C:\EPPlus:

```
 Directory of c:\EPPlus

10/11/2012  12:50 PM    <DIR>          .
10/11/2012  12:50 PM    <DIR>          ..
10/11/2012  12:35 PM           608,256 EPPlus.dll
               1 File(s)        608,256 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  137,501,888,512 bytes free
```

I created the EPPlus.dll by downloading the distribution zip for the library and cut-and-pasting the file into the EPPlus folder, which I created using Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By examining the properties of the EPPlus.dll file in Windows Explorer I found that the file was "blocked" by the operating system because it knew that it had originated on a different computer and was therefore potentially dangerous.  Clicking the "Unblock" button made the file accessible to IronPython.

Thanks, Microsoft!